# How to use tailwindcss colors in custom css classes?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I can use predefined `tailwind` classes to set color in HTML like:

```
<div class="border border-purple-500"></div>
```

But I also would like to use the same color in my custom CSS, like:

```
.my-class {
    border: 1px solid $purple-500;
}
```

Is it possible to get tailwind color value in CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is. You can use `theme()` [directive](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme).

```
.my-class {
    border: 1px solid theme('colors.purple.500');
}
```

or via `@apply`

```
.my-class {
    @apply border border-purple-500;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I know about @apply but it does not work on pseudo classes like :before or :after. That's why I need to access values directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add exact color to tailwind.css inside [ ]. For example

```
 <div class="border border-[#4231d]"></div>
```

You can use the same color in css class:

```
.my-class {
    border: 1px solid #4231d;
}
```